# Counting consecutive instances of numbers greater than value

Tags: excel-formula

I have a challenge to count the number of instances that consecutive values are greater than 12. I want to count the number of times that are consecutive in total. It might be easier to explain with an example of the data. 
Data: 12.1, 12.3,13, 11, 10, 15, 13, 12.1, 11, 12.2, 13.1 
Should return 5 - ie 5 times that 2 numbers next to one another are >12. NOT 3, where there 3 'groups' of cells all greater than 12 in each cell.

Current formula I am working with is:
     =SUM(INT(FREQUENCY(IF(data>12,COLUMN(data)),IF(data<12,COLUMN(data)))>=2))

Where "data" is the range I am trying to count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is in `A1` to `K1`, this should work

```
{=SUM((A1:K1>12)*(B1:L1>12))}
```

Note that the `{...}` indicate an array formula, so copy the formula without them and enter with `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER`.

The `*` is equivalent to `AND` in an array, so basically this formula sums up all instances, where both conditions within parenthesis are `TRUE` (`TRUE = 1`).

Comment: Actually, you can also use `SUMPRODUCT` instead of `SUM`. Then you don't need an array, which might be faster in case your data set is large.

Comment: Genius! Worked perfectly and far simpler than I thought it would be!